# Is it possible to add text to top of the body of a jekyll post without it being previewed in the listing of posts?

Tags: markdown, jekyll, github-pages

Is there a way to add some text to the top of the body of a Jekyll post but hide it when generating the preview in the list of posts?

I added two images to illustrate what I mean.

**Post preview:**
[image]

**Post:**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you can do it in Markdown, but you can do it in HTML. I think you can put the HTML into the Markdown file.

In the front matter, you can have an attribute called `extraText`.

```
---

...

extraText: Here I want to add some...
---
```

Then in the body of the post, add an if-check for the attribute. If it's there, show the text.

```
{% if page.extraText %}
    <p>{{ page.extraText }}</p>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, see https://imgur.com/a/EtZ2sPy and https://imgur.com/a/4qTDXPN

Comment: Ah, then it seems I misunderstood what you are doing to preview a post vs showing the full post. How are you showing the preview of a post?